# Gorm: Can't delete after removeFrom

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a (to me very strange) problem with Gorm.

We have to clean up some data in our project and everything except for one thing works fine.

Here's an excerpt of our domain classes

```
class Person {
    ...
}

class Grade {
   ...
   static hasMany = [speaker: Person]
}
```

Now I'm searching for a specific bunch of people to delete (duplicates). After I found them, I need to switch over all instances of the to-be-deleted person to the remaining one. Here's an excerpt of that logic:

```
def personDelete = Person.get(it.get("bhlneuPerson"))
def personBase = Person.get(it.get("bhlPerson"))

...

def grades = Grade.withCriteria {
    speaker {
        eq("id", personDelete.id)
    }
}
grades.each {
    it.removeFromSpeaker(personDelete)
    it.addToSpeaker(personBase)
    it.save(failOnError: true)
}

...
```

After that I collect all the ids I found in a list and iterate over it to delete the corresponding persons

```
people.each {
    def pers = Person.get(it)
    if(pers)
        pers.delete()
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
| Error 2015-09-01 15:02:36,256 [http-bio-8080-exec-15] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ObjectDeletedException occurred when processing request: [GET] /migration/testBHLNEU
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Person#3970]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Person#3970]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Person#3970]
Line | Method
->>  200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Person#3970]
```

After the execution there is still a grade object with the old person's id (#3970), but also a new one, which got added during the above execution.

Where is my fault in the logik? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you add a `it.save(flush: true)` right after the `it.removeFromSpeaker()`?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing.
Although I assume it doesn't matter that I put it after the addTo statement. Will try it out to be sure.

Comment: Tested it, didn't change anything